System.Windows.Form not populating variable on button press
The PS below is not populating the variable if a button is selected. However if the keypress 1-2 is selected the printer is selected.
The pushbutton works on the button selection for the language selection but not the printer selection. Keypresses 1-2 areworking. The variable for  $global:printerChoice is not being populated once the printer is selected in the box by $_.Name of the printer. It is empty.
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"

# Initialize global variables
$language = 0
$printerChoice = ""

# Language Selection Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select Language'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 200)
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen  # Center the form
$form.TopMost = $true  # Keep the form in the foreground
$form.KeyPreview = $true  # Ensure the form captures key presses

# Create a label for instructions
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = 'Select your language (1: English, 2: Español):'
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 40)
$form.Controls.Add($label)

# Create buttons for each language
$buttonEnglish = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonEnglish.Text = "1. English"
$buttonEnglish.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 60)
$buttonEnglish.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260, 40)
$buttonEnglish.Add_Click({
    $global:language = 1
    Write-Host "Language selected: English (1)"
    $form.Close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonEnglish)

$buttonSpanish = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonSpanish.Text = "2. Español"
$buttonSpanish.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 110)
$buttonSpanish.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260, 40)
$buttonSpanish.Add_Click({
    $global:language = 2
    Write-Host "Language selected: Español (2)"
    $form.Close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonSpanish)

# KeyDown event for capturing keyboard and numpad inputs
$form.Add_KeyDown({
    $key = $_.KeyCode
    Write-Host "Key pressed: $key"

    if ($key -eq [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D1 -or $key -eq [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad1) {
        $global:language = 1
        Write-Host "Language selected: English (1)"
        $form.Close()
    } elseif ($key -eq [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D2 -or $key -eq [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad2) {
        $global:language = 2
        Write-Host "Language selected: Español (2)"
        $form.Close()
    }
})

# Show the form for language selection
$form.ShowDialog()

# Output the selected language for debugging
Write-Host "Selected Language: $global:language"

# Set language messages based on selection
if ($global:language -eq 2) {
    $langMessage = @{
        "choosePrinter" = "Seleccione su impresora desde la lista."
        "setDefault" = "La impresora predeterminada ha sido configurada."
        "orientationLandscape" = "La orientación de la impresora está en horizontal."
        "orientationNotLandscape" = "La orientación de la impresora no está en horizontal. Comuníquese con el supervisor coordinador o con el departamento de TI para configurarla."
        "noPrinterSelected" = "No se seleccionó ninguna impresora. Seleccione una impresora predeterminada para sus facturas."
        "printerError" = "Error al obtener información de la impresora. Verifique la impresora seleccionada."
        "methodInvocationError" = "Hubo un error al configurar la impresora predeterminada."
        "orientationError" = "Error al verificar la orientación de la impresora."
    }
} else {
    $langMessage = @{
        "choosePrinter" = "Please choose your printer from the list."
        "setDefault" = "The default printer has been set."
        "orientationLandscape" = "The printer orientation is in Landscape."
        "orientationNotLandscape" = "The printer orientation is not in Landscape. Contact Supervisor Coordinator or IT to set the printer orientation."
        "noPrinterSelected" = "No printer selected. Please Select a default printer for your invoices."
        "printerError" = "Error getting printer information. Please check the selected printer."
        "methodInvocationError" = "There was an error setting the default printer."
        "orientationError" = "Error checking printer orientation."
    }
}

# Fetch the list of printers
$printers = Get-Printer | Select-Object Name
$printersCount = $printers.Count
Write-Host "Printers found: $printersCount"

# Create the form for printer selection
$printerForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$printerForm.Text = $langMessage["choosePrinter"]
$printerForm.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen  # Center the form
$printerForm.TopMost = $true  # Keep the form in the foreground

# Calculate the size of the printer form based on the number of printers
$buttonHeight = 40
$padding = 20
$formHeight = $printersCount * ($buttonHeight + $padding) + 100  # Add extra space for form controls
$printerForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, $formHeight)
$printerForm.KeyPreview = $true  # Ensure the form captures key presses

# Create buttons for each printer
$buttons = @()
$yOffset = 60
$printers | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $yOffset = 60  # Start position for the first button
} -Process {
    Write-Host "Creating button for printer: $($_.Name)"  # Debugging message to check printer name
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Text = "$($printers.IndexOf($_) + 1). $($_.Name)"
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $yOffset)
    $button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260, $buttonHeight)
    $button.Add_Click({
        Write-Host "Button clicked for printer: $($_.Name)"  # Debugging button click
        $global:printerChoice = $_.Name
        Write-Host "Printer selected: $global:printerChoice"  # Verify the selection
        $printerForm.Close()
    })
    $printerForm.Controls.Add($button)
    $yOffset += $buttonHeight + $padding  # Increase Y position for next button
    $buttons += $button
}

# KeyDown event for capturing keyboard and numpad inputs for printer selection
$printerForm.Add_KeyDown({
    $key = $_.KeyCode
    Write-Host "Key pressed for printer selection: $key"
    $index = -1

    # Check for number key press
    if ($key -ge [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D1 -and $key -le [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D9) {
        $index = $key - [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D1
    } elseif ($key -ge [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad1 -and $key -le [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad9) {
        $index = $key - [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad1
    }

    if ($index -ge 0 -and $index -lt $printersCount) {
        Write-Host "Selected printer from key press: $($printers[$index].Name)"  # Debugging key press
        $global:printerChoice = $printers[$index].Name
        $printerForm.Close()
    }
})

# Show the printer selection form
$printerForm.ShowDialog()

# Output the selected printer for debugging
Write-Host "Selected Printer: $global:printerChoice"

# Proceed with printer selection if valid choice is made
if (-not $printerChoice) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($langMessage["noPrinterSelected"], "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    return
}

# Set the printer as the default
try {
    Write-Host "Attempting to set $global:printerChoice as default printer."
    $Printer = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='$global:printerChoice'"
    if (-not $Printer) {
        Write-Host "Error: Printer not found."
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($langMessage["printerError"], "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        return
    }
    Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $Printer -MethodName SetDefaultPrinter | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Default printer set to: $global:printerChoice"
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$global:printerChoice $($langMessage['setDefault'])", "Success", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error setting default printer: $_"
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($langMessage["methodInvocationError"], "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
}


Debug output:
Language selected: English (1)
Cancel
Selected Language: 1
Printers found: 5
Creating button for printer: Snagit 2024
Creating button for printer: OneNote for Windows 10
Creating button for printer: PDF Writer - bioPDF
Creating button for printer: OneNote (Desktop)
Creating button for printer: HP LaserJet Pro M402-M403 n-dne PCL 6
Button clicked for printer:
Printer selected:
Cancel
Selected Printer:
OK

I'm pretty confident that you're hitting a scoping issue here, and $_ is no longer the same thing. Maybe try a ForEach($Printer in $Printers) loop and see if you don't get different results there. Making your buttons dynamically may be problematic. You might have to make a hashtable for printers, and actually loop through that making buttons for each thing there. If the ForEach($Printer in $Printers) thing doesn't work I have an idea for that.

Inside a form's event handler like Add_Click(), the $_ automatic variable is the EventArgs object, and not the printer you are iterating. To get access to the iterated printer name, you could store it in the buttons own .Tag property with $button.Tag = $_.Name and inside the Add_Click({..}) use $this.Tag instead of $_.Name. See this answer where $this and $_ inside windows forms eventhandlers are explained

Also, scoping variables with $global: seems overkill. Try $script: instead

As commented, inside an event handler like Add_Click({..}), the $_ automatic variable is NOT the printer you are iterating, but instead it is the EventArgs for the handler.
In an Add_Click() event handler this would be an object describing the mouse click itself (position, left or right button, etc.)
To keep the printer name nicely together with the corresponding button, I'd suggest storing this printername inside the button's own .Tag property:
Try:
$printers = Get-Printer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name  # just the name. for short use (Get-Printer).Name
$printersCount = @($printers).Count

# Create buttons for each printer
$buttonHeight = 40
$padding      = 20
$yOffset      = 60 # Start position for the first button
$index        = 1  # for the button text

# your code does not show any reason for collecting the buttons in a variable $buttons, but
# if you do need it, collect the array like below and do not use $buttons += $button
$buttons = $printers | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Creating button for printer: $_"  # Debugging message to check printer name
    $button          = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]::new()
    $button.Text     = '{0}. {1}' -f $index++, $_
    $button.Tag      = $_                         # store the printer name in the .Tag property
    $button.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(10, $yOffset)
    $button.Size     = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(260, $buttonHeight)
    $button.Add_Click({
        # now, the button has the actual printername in its .Tag property
        $printerName = $this.Tag  # for convenience
        Write-Host "Button clicked for printer: $printerName"  # Debugging button click
        $global:printerChoice = $printerName                   # try $script: scope instead
        Write-Host "Printer selected: $global:printerChoice"   # Verify the selection
        $printerForm.Close()
    })
    $printerForm.Controls.Add($button)
    $yOffset += $buttonHeight + $padding  # Increase Y position for next button
    $button                               # output the new object to be captured in variable $buttons
}

Of course, since I have now added only the printer Names (strings) in variable $printers instead of objects with one property called .Name, you also need to change the $printerForm.Add_KeyDown({..}) into:
$printerForm.Add_KeyDown({
    $key = $_.KeyCode
    Write-Host "Key pressed for printer selection: $key"
    $index = -1

    # Check for number key press
    if ($key -ge [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D1 -and $key -le [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D9) {
        $index = $key - [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::D1
    } elseif ($key -ge [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad1 -and $key -le [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad9) {
        $index = $key - [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::NumPad1
    }

    if ($index -ge 0 -and $index -lt $script:printersCount) {
        Write-Host "Selected printer from key press: $($printers[$index])"  # Debugging key press
        $global:printerChoice = $printers[$index]
        $printerForm.Close()
    }
})

After use, don't forget to remove the form from memory with
$printerForm.Dispose()

I'm using the new syntax for defining the System.Drawing objects here. Of course, New-Object .. also works, but this way should be a bit faster. You will need PowerShell version 5 and up for this however

Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form'."
At line:145 char:1

$printerForm.ShowDialog()

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ObjectDisposedException




Selected Printer:
OK

@Vincent You need to dispose of the used form AFTER .ShowDialog(). Do this for both forms. $form.ShowDialog(); $form.Dispose() for the language form and  $$printerForm.ShowDialog(); $printerForm.Dispose()  for the second form you created

@Vincent Sorry, that last one should be $printerForm, not $$printerForm

Great writeup, thanks for the effort. I couldn't remember what context the $_ automatic variable would take, and was too lazy to look it up. I'm glad somebody else took the time to write up a real answer for this. PowerShell scoping issues happen way too often it seems. There should be better error handling for it IMHO.
